# Command raised an exception: TypeError: get_cog() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: discord, discord.py

I was trying to make a discord help command in cog, but I have a problem

when I run this code:

````
@commands.command()
    async def help2(self, ctx, * cog):
        embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Commands of {self.bot.user.name}")
        
        for command in self.bot.get_cog("Ban", "Kick").get_commands():
            embed.add_field(name=f"{command.name} - {command.description}.", value=f"↳ **Syntax:** `{command.usage}`")
        
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)

@help2.error
    async def help2_error(self, ctx, error):
        await ctx.send(f"```{error}```")
````

The bot gives me this error:

```
Command raised an exception: TypeError: get_cog() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

I want to put multiple cogs  `self.bot.get_cog(" ")` but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use multiple `get_cog()`

Reference: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=get_cog#discord.ext.commands.Bot.get_cog

Comment: so I must use `get_cog()` for each cog, there is no other way?